# I got an error when I uploaded a image from Swift app to a server

Tags: python, ios, swift, django, xcode

I got an error when I uploaded a image from Swift app to a Django server, but I cannot understand the error's meaning.
Traceback is

```
objc[31747]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11aa7d998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x119968880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2017-06-16 23:11:52.837756 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350088] [Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
2017-06-16 23:11:54.274757 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350153] [] nw_socket_get_input_frames recvmsg(fd 13, 1024 bytes): [54] Connection reset by peer
2017-06-16 23:11:54.276896 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350153] [] nw_endpoint_flow_prepare_output_frames [1 127.0.0.1:8000 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Failed to use 1 frames, marking as failed
2017-06-16 23:11:54.277301 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350153] [] nw_socket_write_close shutdown(13, SHUT_WR): [57] Socket is not connected
2017-06-16 23:11:54.277684 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350153] [] nw_endpoint_flow_service_writes [1 127.0.0.1:8000 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Write request has 0 frame count, 0 byte count
2017-06-16 23:11:54.278467 Kenshin_Swift[31747:1350154] [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled
error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60800025cda0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/upload_save/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/upload_save/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.})
```

I wrote right url in Swift which is used to upload image, and the url can be accessed by server's being run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`,and I run my server for being able to access from other devises which it means emulator in Xcode(it is not my iPhone emulator)
So,I do not know this error's meaning, what should I do to fix?Swift code is

```
func myImageUploadRequest()
    {

        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/upload_save/");
        //let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.boredwear.com/utils/postImage.php");

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";
        //ユーザーごとに割り振りたい
        let param = [
            "firstName"  : "Sergey",
            "lastName"    : "Kargopolov",
            "userId"    : "9"
        ]

        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        guard let myImage = myImageView.image else {
            return
        }

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image!, 1)

        if(imageData==nil)  { return; }

        request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData! as NSData, boundary: boundary) as Data


        myActivityIndicator.startAnimating();

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("******* response = \(response)")

            // Print out reponse body
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary


                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.myImageView.image = nil;
                }

            }catch
            {
                print(error)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }


    func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
        let body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        let filename = "user-profile.jpg"
        let mimetype = "image/jpg"

        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(imageDataKey as Data)
        body.appendString(string: "\r\n")



        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body
    }

    func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
        return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    }    
}
extension NSMutableData {
    func appendString(string: String) {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        append(data!)
    }
```

Furthermore,my Django server code is

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from .forms import RegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .models import Post
from .forms import UserImageForm
from .models import ImageAndUser

def index(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/index.html', context)


@login_required
def profile(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/profile.html', context)


def regist(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/regist.html', context)

def index(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/index.html', context)


@login_required
def profile(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/profile.html', context)


def regist(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/regist.html', context)


@require_POST
def regist_save(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        login(request, user)
        context = {
            'user': request.user,
        }
        return redirect('profile')


    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/regist.html', context)

@login_required
def photo(request):
    d = {
        'photos': Post.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/profile.html', d)


def upload(request, p_id):
    form = UserImageForm(request.POST or None)
    d = {
        'p_id': p_id,
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/photo.html', d)


def upload_save(request):

    photo_id = request.POST.get("p_id", "")

    if (photo_id):
        photo_obj = Post.objects.get(id=photo_id)
    else:
        photo_obj = Post()

    files = request.FILES.getlist("files[]")


    photo_obj.image = files[0]
    # photo_obj.image2 = files[1]
    # photo_obj.image3 = files[2]

    photo_obj.save()
    # return render(request, "registration/accounts/photo.html")

    photos = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        'photos': photos,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/photo.html', context)

def kenshinresults(request):
    d = {
        'results': results,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/kenshin_result.html', d)

def tc(request):
    tcresults = ImageAndUser.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('id').last()
    d = {
        'tcresults': tcresults,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/tc.html', d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is simple, Swift can't access the IP:port at 127.0.0.1.

To solve that :

1. check that no other server is listening on 127.0.0.1:8000
2. go to the http://127.0.0.1:8000 address with your normal browser and check is Django is answering
3. go to http://127.0.0.1:8000 address with your iPhone browser to confirm

It may be that 127.0.0.1 does not mean django for your iPhone simulator, try with your external IP.